# How to set all <v-col> one below each other on mobile devices only?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuetify.js

How to have the following `<v-col>` all one below each other on mobile devices only ?

```
<v-container>
  <v-row>
    <v-col>A</v-col>
    <v-col>B</v-col>
  </v-row>
  <v-row>
    <v-col>C</v-col>
    <v-col>D</v-col>
  </v-row>
<v-container>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set value of the prop `cols` to span over the 12 columns.

```
<v-container>
  <v-row>
    <v-col cols="12" sm="6">A</v-col>
    <v-col cols="12" sm="6">B</v-col>
  </v-row>
  <v-row>
    <v-col cols="12" sm="6">C</v-col>
    <v-col cols="12" sm="6">D</v-col>
  </v-row>
<v-container>
```

The above code will display the columns on each other on mobile only.
From the `sm` breakpoint and up, each column will span over half of the viewport.

Demo on [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/begueradj-the-sasster/pen/vYGKGZX?editable=true&editors=101%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fvuetifyjs.com%2Fen%2Fcomponents%2Fgrids%2F).

This is what it shows once on mobile viewport:

[image]

And if the viewport is wider than the mobile one, we get this:

[image]

Comment: Nice. But it's actually doing the contrary of what I need.

Comment: Indeed ... is my edited feedback what you are looking for ?